# ios which is the best way to pass data from one viewcontroller to another . through singleton class or *.h file?

Tags: ios

I'm new to iOS, my question is: What is the best way to pass data from one UIViewController to another, through singleton class or *.h file?

Comment: Refer this :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers/22934200#22934200

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) use properties to pass data.

```
- (void)someMethod {
  MyViewController * vc = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:"MyViewController" bundle:nil];
  vc.someData = data;
}
```

Also if you use Segues you should do it `prepareForSegue` method

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    MyViewController *vc = segue.destinationViewController;
    vc.someData = data;
}
```

Comment: thank you @Konstantin Koval , when i use singleton class?

Comment: you can pass a singleton this way if you want. 
vc.someData = [MyDataStorage sharedInstance];

Comment: you can read answer here 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers?lq=1

Comment: we can pass data through public property, then why we are using protocol